# Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 Standard to Developer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Standard edition and I want to upgrade it to Developer version.  I installed the Standard version for my MSDN subscription.  I have tried to upgrade from the Standard ISO and Developer ISO and it does not give you an option to upgrade.  It ask for a product key but MSDN states "No key is required for this product" for Developer version.  This should be real simple.  How do I upgrade from Standard to Developer using the ISO's on my MSDN subscription?

Comment: Just install a new instance.  Delete the Standard Edition if you like

Comment: And don't forget... you can't use dev edition for production databases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just install the developer version next to the standard version. You can uninstall the standard edition if you want. The database .mdf files can be used by either. Detach them from the standard edition and attach them to the developer edition.

Answer (score 4):

You should just be able to do it using the ["Edition Upgrade" option](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2011/01/24/how-to-perform-an-sql-server-edition-upgrade.aspx) from the Maintenance portion of the Installation Center.

If that doesn't work, you might also try constructing a [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) to the setup program, using `/ACTION=editionupgrade`, among other parameters.